# jQuery hasClass 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check with jQuery which li element from a list of li elements is the active one (they represent a menu, and I want to check which menu item is currently active).

So, I store all the li items in a variable, myElements. Then I ask the length of myElements, and apply some style changes to them, up to here everything works. Apparently this way my variable myElements is a Nodelist, not an array, so I declare another variable; myElements_array, which contains the same elements as myElements and is an array (also tested and it works).

Then I try to check which of the elements from myElements_array has the 'current-menu-item' class, but it doesn't work and the google chrome console says there's an error: 'Uncaught TypeError: myElements_array[j].hasClass is not a function'. Does anyone have an idea what the reason might be?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myElements = jQuery("#navbar > ul > li");
var count = myElements.length;

for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
myElements[i].style.width = (100/count)+'%';
}

var myElements_array = [];
for(var i = myElements.length; i--; myElements_array.unshift(myElements[i]));

var j = 0;
while (! myElements_array[j].hasClass('current-menu-parent') ) {
j++;
}
document.write(j);
</script>
```

Comment: myElements_array[j] may not be an valid DOM object

Comment: @A.B Um, it is a DOM object...

Comment: `.hasClass` is a jQuery method, it can't be called on DOM objects.

Comment: `var j = jQuery("#navbar > ul > li.current-menu-parent").length;`

Comment: @epascarello i wanted to say the reverse thing, is not a jquery object instead of DOM:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem is the index you are pulling from the array is a DOM node when you use bracket notation and it is not a jQuery object. DOM does not have hasClass.

You can either store the jQuery version or change it to jQuery

```
while (! $(myElements_array[j]).hasClass('current-menu-parent') ) {
```

or use classList contains

```
while (! myElements_array[j].classList.contains('current-menu-parent') ) {
```

or use `eq()` instead of referencing the DOM

```
while (! myElements_array.eq(j).hasClass('current-menu-parent') ) {
```

Answer (score 4):

When you access a jQuery object as if it's an array, it returns the raw DOM element object, not a jQuery object. If you want a jQuery object, use `.eq()` rather than an array index:

```
while (myElements.eq(j).hasClass('current-menu-parent') ) {
    j++;
}
```

You could also use:

```
j = myElements.index(myElements.find(".current-menu-parent:first"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't loop through elements inside an jQuery object like that. You're tyring to use jQuery methods on normal dom objects. Use this instead:

```
$("#navbar > ul > li").each(function(){
    $(this).hasClass("current-menu-parent");
});
```